# Why all that fuzz about the virtual keyword?

Tags: c++, performance, boost, virtual

When reading the documentation of one or another boost library, I encountered some statements giving a hint that the `virtual` keyword is kind of evil. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/msm/doc/HTML/ch03s05.html, for example:

> It will not be said that MSM forces the virtual keyword down your throat!

According to http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.4, the virtual keyword is really not that bad, and my feeling about it is the same.

Why do some of the boost people regard virtual function calls as the worst thing ever? I have the impression that the boost guys are really **the** experts on C++, so there must be something about it.

Comment: You made a wrong conclusion, it is not said anywhere in that doc that "virtual keyword is kind of evil".

Comment: Vote to close: I don't think anyone has said that `virtual` is "evil" (or anything similar), so this question is somewhat difficult to answer.

Comment: I don't think the text you quote is intended to imply that keyword virtual is "evil". It says "You might want to call non-virtually a method of the currently active states", so I think "not force virtual down throat" means "allow you to use non-virtual". The fact that non-virtual functions have uses doesn't imply that virtual is evil.

Comment: There were other examples, I just cannot find them at the moment. Of course, my interpretation of the citation is (intentionally) a bit exaggerated. I just wanted to collect different views on the topic, that's all.

Answer (score 3):

there is case where static polymorphism is preferred to dynamic one. That's what Christophe states here. Nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Runtime polymorphism has an extra cost, namely the vtable. Once the vtable is added in a type, it can't be removed. One of the core strengths of C++ is that "you only pay for what you use". Therefore, to keep objects as lean as possible, several libraries avoid virtual functions when possible. Not because it is evil, but because you may not want it.

Comment: Yeah I got that, see the link in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the inference is that MSM does not, through its inner workings or structure, force you to declare members of your own code as virtual, or to override theirs. There are libraries that require this, for instance libraries that dynamically create "proxies" of your classes such as mocks or lazy-loaders.

Comment: Can you give an example or reference of such a library? I'd be interested in how this would work.

Comment: I don't have C++ examples, but over in the .NET area, the NHibernate ORM requires mapped domain classes to have all their members declared virtual, so it can create lazy-loading proxies.